# Get all owned stocks Info on Robinhood api- Py

Tags: python

Is there a way or method that gets all the owned stocks/Cryptos' info, such as its quantity?

For example if I owned a total of 2 stocks and that is "CCL" and "CUK" how can I get a List of the names/symbols- something like this ["CCL","CUK"].

Comment: I think your question is incomplete, as you didn't mention that from where you are retrieving the stocks. If you are hard coding it, This is simple just to initialize the list for eg. `stocks = ["CCL", "CUK"]`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I want to retrieve all the stocks owned by a user in their Robinhood account using the Robinhood api, I’m not really sure where I can retrieve that information.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called [pyrh](https://pyrh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for accessing the RobinHood API.

After authenticating like described in the documentation of the library, you can use the methods the class pyrh.Robinhood provides like `portfolio()` to gather the data.

Something like this might work.

```
from pyrh import Robinhood

rh = Robinhood()
rh.login(username="YOUR_EMAIL", password="YOUR_PASSWORD")

data = rh.portfolio()
```

I am not sure in what form the portfolio data comes, so you might need to iterate over it to convert it to a list.

Answer (score 1):

A currently maintained python library for Robinhood API is [robin_stocks](https://github.com/jmfernandes/robin_stocks)

In order to get the stocks in your portfolio you'd first need to authenticate with something like:

```
import robin_stocks as r
r.login("yourusername","yourpassword")
```

Then use a function such as `build_holdings()` which will return information about the holdings of your account.

```
holdings = r.account.build_holdings()
```

Which returns:

> Returns a dictionary where the keys are the stock tickers and the value is another dictionary that has the stock price, quantity held, equity, percent change, equity change, type, name, id, pe ratio, percentage of portfolio, and average buy price.

Including all the held stocks. The library docs are [here](https://robin-stocks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#robin_stocks.account.build_holdings)